# Service Worker + Socket.io: overwrite cached page on new visit

Tags: sockets, caching, socket.io, fetch, service-worker

I'm working with a Service Worker and Socket.io for a mobile scorekeeping app. The scores are stored in a database and rendered in HTML and this HTML is cached in the Service Worker. It's kinda what I want to accomplish with the Service Worker, but if the scores are updated it will show the old scores on refresh.

How could I make the Service Worker fetch the latest version of a HTML page each time you visit or refresh the page?

My code for fetching and caching:

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if(response) {
                console.log('found cached response', response);
                return response;
            } else {
                console.log('response not in cache, fetching it');
                return fetchAndCache(event);
            }
        })
    );
});

function fetchAndCache(event) {
    return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return caches.open('UFA-other-1.0').then(function(cache) {
            console.log('fetched and caching', event.request);
            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
            return response;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: Can't you automate it all using [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) from Google?

If not, then their manual library, [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) might offer some strategies that are useful. You could opt for different strategies, such as network-first, or fastest. See more documentation [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/sw-toolbox/docs/master/tutorial-api#expressive-approach).

To answer your question: a service worker, once setup properly, will fetch the latest version of all files you want to cache, but those files won't be used until the next time you load or reload the page.

You'll see at a [Mozilla service worker example page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller) that they show a message indicating the user that a newer version of the page is available, after reloading the page.

Hope that helps!